# CSLogItem timestamp format (NSTimeInterval since when?)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gps

I'm logging CMAccelerometerData on the iphone. CMAcceleration is a subclass of CMLogItem, which defines a timestamp. The timestamp is very important to me, as I have to match CMAcceleration data to positions obtain via GPS. GPS gives me a NSDate object, which is good; but CMLogItem gives me a number that I cant relate to anything.

It's not UNIX time for sure. This morning (17/11/2010 at 11H17am, in Australia), it was at 4090 seconds.

Any ideas of what that could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind I found out, CMLogItem timestamp is a NSTimeInterval starting when the phone last boot up.

Comment: Please, can you mark this question as answered with green check-mark because we don't wont to track it in unanswered list?